# How to propagate error to a client in a service oriented architecture?

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, soa

I am working on some project to practice my skills. My project has a SOA and consists of a application server on one machine , and a database server on another machine. The clients that use this system can be both web and phones. I started to make all the communications within all the components (including the clients) RESTFull. However, soon I realised that there are limitations to this approach. Especially on the clients and app server side. The biggest issue I faced is that how I can propagate an error to a client. Lets say the client send a request to modify a record in the database. So the request is sent to the app server and the app server will call the database server to do the job. If for some reason something goes wrong, I want the client(web or phone) to know about it (near real-time). One option would be manually propagate the error up to my controller and put the error message in the response to the request and send it back to the client as a response. But I have a feeling that this is not the right way to do it. Is there a better way? I am using Java so any pointers to any documents, blogs, libraries and technologies that can help me with this are welcome.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are designing a REST-ful implementation, you should leverage the HTTP status codes to return error codes to your clients.  Apigee has some great tutorials on REST-ful API design.  I recommend spending some time on their site going through these.

[Here's a good tutorial on error messaging in REST-ful API design](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_what_about_errors).